# Event sourcing: overhead with storing large amount of records in memory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, event-sourcing

I am implementing event sourcing architecture and my aggregates will contains large amount of records in memory. To test how well .NET stores large amount of records in memory, I created a simple program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        int maxRecords = 100000000;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxRecords; i++ )
        {
            dict.Add(i.ToString(), new String('A', 10));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

In the config file, I have:

```
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
```

So I am storing 100 million records and each records is 10 bytes (let's say 20 since it's probably Unicode). So I am storing about 2GB of data in memory. The application however grows to 15GB.

1. Ideally I'd like to store things in an IDictionary. Is there anything I can do to reduce the overhead?
2. If anyone worked on an event sourcing architecture that stores large amount of data in memory, please share your experience with this and how you structured your aggregates.

Comment: Why would you store Aggregates in memory?

Comment: If I store Aggregates in a database, will I then lose some of the benefits of event sourcing like not having to do CRUD operations and object-relational mapping?

Comment: You don't loose anything, and you gain scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Classical solution for this question usually stands on two points:

- Select correct aggregates root, so state of which of them will be small. Because inter-aggregate communication is disallowed, so for perform unitary command, you should load only one small state for one aggregate root. It can easely be retrieved by one async query from database
- Store query side on many different collections, every item on it is segregated by document identifier. So your system process is not have to persist read model in memory.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? When you say "Store query side on many different collections", do you mean in a database?

Comment: @Sandy In general case, store should be represented in higher abstraction layer, and be database-independent. Read model with it's limitation is best for it, because any read-model entity can be split apart in ordered list, like aggragate list.
In SQL server collection is table, and document is table row with unique GUID and no relations with other rows and tables. In mongodb it's natural collection with some Guid'ed documents
(If you like answer, please vote :)